# why wouldn't Allah listen?

Tags: dua, destiny

I have grown up watching bad marriages and financial crisises. I can't remember the last time i was happy. So in order to achieve salvation, I turned my face towards religion. I am not going to deny that i only did it so that Allah would listen to me. And....i prayed and prayed and did almost everything a good muslim is supposed to....wholeheartedly...hoping that Allah will help me and something good will happen to me. But it didn't. I have watched my parents being 'good muslims' throughout their lives and nothing good ever happens to them. My mother works really hard to provide for our family and she is a nice person but she ended up in a bad marriage with all kinds of miseries as gift and it has been the same for decades whereas I see other women just sitting at home, doing nothing other than being spendthrift, stubborn, quarrelsome and gossip-y and they get all the things in life even if they don't pray? Isn't it just unfair? So...after years of enduring everything and praying and getting nothing but disappointment, i turned away from Islam thinking that Allah doesn't listen. And i feel lost right now. I don't want to go back to the faith as i don't have it in me anymore to go through any mofe disappointments. So, brothers and sisters out there, tell me, what should I do now? (PS...i am familiar with the Hadith about our duas getting recieved in any of the three ways. It just seems like Allah is hell bent on the fact that mine always go the last two ways. It never goes the first way.)

Comment: See also: "Qur'an [9:53-55](http://quran.com/9/53-55)"

Comment: This looks like a general call for advice rather than a practical and answerable *question*; please note that we are not a typical Internet forum and these highly personal sorts of question, which attract speculation and opinion rather than practical *answers*, do not really work well here (see: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Asalaamu alaikum, sister.

I am so sorry that you feel lost, disappointed, and unhappy. You and your family seem to be in a tough situation.

You have asked two questions, and I will do my best to answer them.

1. Why wouldn't Allah listen?

Another way to ask this would be, **does Allah listen? And if Allah listens, does Allah respond? And if Allah listens, are there times when Allah doesn't listen or won't respond?**

So let's go one by one. **Yes, Allah listens** to those who call upon Allah.

"*Call upon Me, and I will answer you. (40:60)*"

"*And when My servants ask you concerning Me, then surely I am very near; I answer the prayer of the suppliant when he calls on Me, so they should answer My call and believe in Me that they may walk in the right way. (2:186)*"

And does Allah respond to duas?

**Yes, Allah responds to dua**. As you mentioned, there are three responses to duas/prayers.

> It was narrated from Abu Saeed (R.A) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “There is no Muslim who does not offer any Dua in which there is no sin or severing of family ties but Allah will give him one of three things in return: either He will answer his Dua sooner, or he will store it up for him in the Hereafter, or He will divert an equivalent evil away from him because of it.” They said: “We will say a lot of Dua.” The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah is more generous.” [Narrated by Ahmad, 10749]

You may not particularly like the response of Allah, and you may choose to be ungrateful about the way that Allah answers your duas, but you know that *"it may be that you dislike a thing while it is good for you, and it may be that you love a thing while it is evil for you, and Allah knows, while you do not know. (2:216)*"

But is there a time when Allah does not listen to us?

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “The slave will receive a response so long as his du’aa’ does not involve sin or severing of family ties, and so long as he is not hasty.” It was said, “What does being hasty mean?” He said: “When he says, ‘I made du’aa’ and I made du’aa’, and I have not seen any response,’ and he gets frustrated and stops making du’aa’.” [Narrated by al-Bukahari, 6340; Muslim, 2735.]

So if you are making dua to harm someone, to sin, or to sever relations within a family, those duas will not receive responses. It also says that **if you stop making dua**, as you feel you have not been getting a response, **then Allah stops responding.**

And Allah knows best.

2. What should you do now?

*So **be patient with a beautiful patience**. (70:5)*

If you know Sura Al-Fatiha, which Muslims recite in every rakat of every salah/namaz, the fifth ayat/verse says: *It is You we worship and You we ask for help. (1:05)*.

Trust that Allah listens to you and to every person who calls out to
   Allah. Trust that Allah responds to you, and trust that Allah's
   response is the best response. Make your salah/namaz. Continue to make dua, continue to ask Allah and Allah alone for help, and **continue to thank Allah for the many blessings which Allah has bestowed upon you and your family**.

*So which of the favors of your Lord would you deny? (55:38)*

If you cannot think of positive blessings in your life (health, enough food, a safe place to sleep, warm clothing, the gift of the deen) -- and it does sound as if your family's situation is difficult -- think of what you have been spared from by the mercy of Allah. Perhaps you could make dua using a wonderful dua called  [Dua Jaushan E Sagheer](http://www.duas.org/jsagheer_alt.htm). A small excerpt is below:

> My God, many a living being is constantly in fear, terrified, sleepless, forsaken, alone, timid, fugitive, exiled, petrified, caught in distress, running away in frustration, and in the wide world, there is no place to rest for a while, neither can devise or find a way out, or escape, but I am safe, secure, satisfied, and comfortable. 
>   So praise be to Thee, O Lord, in [Thy] invulnerable Omnipotence, and prudent Forbearance. Bless Muhammad and the family of Muhammad, and let me be among those who thank Thee for Thy bounties and remember Thee for Thy favours.

And in everything, say *Alhamdullilah*.

May Allah guide you and all of us on the right path, and may you and your family know peace in this life and in the hereafter.

For further reading, please see [this article](http://muslimmatters.org/2014/12/05/when-you-feel-like-allah-doesnt-listen/).